# Subset a data frame based on elements in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

This seems like a simple thing to do and I was wondering what the most efficient way to do this was. Suppose I have a dataframe "data" and another frame that has the indices that I want to extract.

```
data<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,3))
idx<-cbind(c(1,3,2),c(2,3,1))
```

is there an easy way to get the elements pointed to by idx assuming the first row is row id and the second row is column id?

I tried  `data[idx[,1],idx[,2]]` hoping that would work but that didn't.

```
     [,1] [,2]  element
[1,]    1    2   4
[2,]    3    3   9
[3,]    2    1   2
```

I am trying to get the element list in a separate list or vector.

Comment: R can use matrix indexing - `data[idx]` See `?\`[\`` - "*When indexing arrays by ‘[’ a single argument ‘i’ can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of ‘x’; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of ‘i’.*"

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I actually have read in two data frames from files. data and idx. when I tried data[idx] I got this error: Error in `[.default`(data, idx) : invalid subscript type 'idx'

Comment: Then try `data[as.matrix(idx)]`

Comment: probably worth noting that using the matrix indexing coerces data to a matrix

Comment: @nongkrong - I'm not sure that's a problem - if it's going to be output as a vector, it has to be all the same class by definition.

Comment: @thelatemail I only meant it as an addendum to your comment.  The only difference I can think of would be a perfomance issue if you were subsetting a bazillion times.

Comment: @nongkrong: matrix indexing using "[" does not coerce data.frames to matrix.

Comment: @BondedDust are you sure?  on the `help("[.data.frame")` is says "Matrix indexing ('x[i]' with a logical or a 2-column integer matrix 'i') using '[' is not recommended.  For extraction, 'x' is first coerced to a matrix. " But, I don;t know how to test it for sure.

Comment: I've generally used '[<-.data.frame', so will need to check when I have access to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
 data[ cbind( idx[,1],idx[,2]) ]
```